# 'Sometime back' or 'Sometimes back'?

Tags: phrases, expression-choice

How should I decide between "sometime back" and "sometimes back"?

> Sometime back I received a call from Mr. X
>
> Sometimes back I received a call from Mr. X

Which sentence is correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

'Sometime' refers to a single instance, which fits with the single telephone call.

'Sometimes' refers to a number of instances, in which case you would need to refer to more than one call, but you wouldn't use 'sometimes back'.

You have a typo and a missing article. The 1st phrase should be 'Sometime back I received a call from Mr X'.

You can also use 'A while ago' - 'One day/night'.

Comment: It may be that OP actually wants *Some time back*.

Answer (score 3):

For your example the best choice would be

```
Some time ago I received a call from Mr.X.
```

`Sometime` refers to a moment of time, not a period, so saying `sometime back` is equivalent to something like `Last year back` or `On my birthday back`. `Back` is more correctly used with `when` or `in`:

- Back in 90's we would never think about that.
- Back when we didn't know each other, ...
- Back in the day, ... (this one is more idiomatic, meaning at a previous time with some other circumstances)

Sometime can be correctly used to express some important (for the 1st self) things that happened or will happen.

- He will be coming sometime between 6 and 9.
- The bank was robbed sometime last week.

It can also be used as an adjective meaning happening previously, but not now:

- The sometime renowned director is now asking for a new job.

And finally, always remember that there are three different versions:

- Sometimes = occasionally, from time to time
- Sometime = at a certain time, or moment
- Some time = a period of time, a while